# MySQL Daemonize Process 100 Cpu

Tags: mysql, process, daemon

My main server has MYSQL installed, i have a lot of sql proccess, but there is one which makes my cpu to 100%
This is the process which i talk: '/ usr / sbin / mysqld --daemonize --pid-file = / run / mysqld / mysqld.pid / usr / sbin / mysqld'

I need help in the way to find a method to display the which query makes this process to high the cpu '/ usr / sbin / mysqld --daemonize --pid-file = / run / mysqld / mysqld.pid / usr / sbin / mysqld '. I have used this command on SQL 'show processlist;' but i do not have too much information about the process. Also the CPU with this process goes to 100 but my memory ram increases slowly until it gets to 100

This is the information about MySQL Version
'Your MySQL connection id is 4134144, Server version: 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'

I am looking forward to your answers, thanks.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; taken when CPU is at 100% for assistance

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue. Haven't found an answer yet. This post might help to dig down further https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/high-load-coming-from-usr-sbin-mysqld-daemonize.634225/